# How to give HDFS path in APACHE PIG

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig, hdfs, distributed-computing

I am using this command to create schema in PIG but I am getting error that hdfs path for part-r-00000 cannot be found.

```
movies = LOAD 'hdfs://Hadoop-Master:9000/test/part-r-00000' USING JsonLoader('Released:chararray, Metascore:long, imdbID:chararray, Plot:chararray, Director:chararray, Title:chararray, Actors:chararray, imdbRating:long, imdbVotes:Biginteger, Response:Boolean, AmazonAvgScore:Bigdecimal, Runtime:chararray, Type:chararray, Awards:chararray, Year:chararray, Language:chararray, Rated:chararray, Poster:chararray, Country:chararray, AmazonTitle:chararray, AmazonID:chararray, Genre:chararray, Writer:chararray');
```

Comment: check the file is available in hadoop file system
"hadoop fs -ls hdfs://Hadoop-Master:9000/test/part-r-00000"

Comment: I have checked it and it seems I have not given the complete path.After giving `hdfs://Hadoop-Master:9000/user/hduser/test/part-r-00000`, it worked but when I am running `Dump movies` ,it gives me error on the line `Redirecting to job history server` and then `[main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: cm/195.24.205.60:10020. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS`

Comment: That means that you haven't launched job history service. Not a real problem - task is still executed, but can annoy you with such errors in log

Comment: That problem just solved by starting my history server using mr-jobhistory-daemon.sh start historyserver